# Pyspark writing data from databricks into azure sql: ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, apache-arrow

I am writing data from azure databricks to azure sql using pyspark.
Code works well having no nulls, but when dataframe contains nulls I get following error:

```
databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:300: UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
  Unable to convert the field Product. If this column is not necessary, you may consider dropping it or converting to primitive type before the conversion.
Context: Unsupported type in conversion from Arrow: null
Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' is set to true.
  warnings.warn(msg)

ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring
```

The dataframe must be written to sql, including the nulls. How do I solve this?

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

def to_sql(df, table):
  finaldf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
  finaldf.write.jdbc(url=url, table= table, mode ="overwrite", properties = properties)

 to_sql(data, f"TF_{table.upper()}")
```

**EDIT:**

Solved it creating a function that maps pandas dtypes to sql dtypes and outputs columns and dtypes as one string.

```
def convert_dtype(df):
    df_mssql = {'int64': 'bigint', 'object': 'varchar(200)', 'float64': 'float'}
    mydict = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        if str(df.dtypes[col]) in df_mssql:
            mydict[col] = df_mssql.get(str(df.dtypes[col]))
    l = " ".join([str(k[0] + " " + k[1] + ",") for k in list(mydict.items())])
    return l[:-1]
```

Passing this string to the `createTableColumnTypes` option solved this scenario

```
jdbcDF.write \
    .option("createTableColumnTypes", convert_dtype(df) \
    .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename",
          properties={"user": "username", "password": "password"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you'll need to specify the schema in your write statement. Here's an example from the documentation, also linked below:

```
jdbcDF.write \
    .option("createTableColumnTypes", "name CHAR(64), comments VARCHAR(1024)") \
    .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename",
          properties={"user": "username", "password": "password"})
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I wrote a small function to map the pandas dtypes to one string containing columns and sql dtypes. Will edit this in my post.